# Listing the supported formats of BarcodeImage

Tags: options, metadata

`BarcodeImage["string",format]`  generates a barcode image given a string and barcode format. The supported formats can be read off from its documentation.

Is there a programmatic way to list the supported formats?

Answer (score 8):

Programmatic discoverability of various function options is something that is still not covered well in Mathematica, but some work is being done in this way – as far as I have managed to understand from latest  Live CEOing videos.

Diving into the source code, you can discover an internal list which contains all possible formats.

```
Image`$BarcodeImageFormats

(* {"UPC_A", "EAN_13", "EAN_8", "CODE_39", "CODE_128", "ITF", "QR_CODE",
    "PDF_417", "CODABAR", "AZTEC", "DATA_MATRIX"} *)
```

In fact, there are several different namings allowed for these formats, which are then standardized by `` Image`RecognitionDump`standardizeFormatNames ``. You can extract all possible values with:

```
DeleteDuplicates@
 Cases[Information[Image`RecognitionDump`standardizeFormatNames]["Definitions"], 
  p__?StringQ :> p, Infinity]

(* {"UPC-A", "UPC_A", "UPCA", "UPC", "UPC-E", "UPC_E", "UPCE", "EAN-13", 
    "EAN_13", "EAN13", "EAN-8", "EAN_8", "EAN8", "GS1-14", "GS1_14", 
    "GS114", "GS1", "RSS-14", "RSS14", "RSS_14", "EXPANDEDGS1", 
    "EXPANDED-GS1", "GS1EXPANDED", "GS1-EXPANDED", "GS1_EXPANDED", 
    "RSS-EXPANDED", "RSS_EXPANDED", "RSSEXPANDED", "EXPANDED-RSS", 
    "EXPANDEDRSS", "CODE-39", "CODE_39", "CODE39", "CODE-93", "CODE_93", 
    "CODE93", "CODE-128", "CODE_128", "CODE128", "ITF", "QR", "QR-CODE", 
    "QR_CODE", "QRCODE", "DATA-MATRIX", "DATA_MATRIX", "DATAMATRIX", 
    "AZTEC", "PDF-417", "PDF_417", "PDF417", "CODABAR", "MAXICODE"} *)
```

Comment: +1 I was expecting a much more convoluted hack (parsing the docs maybe) but this is definitely a lot simpler and will work till API support comes along. Thnx.

Comment: Note however that the literals (probably var names) differ from those mentioned in the docs ("QR_CODE" instead of "QR"), albeit they work.

Comment: Yes, there is an auxiliary function ``Image`RecognitionDump`standardizeFormatNames`` that converts many different spellings into the "standardized" format names. Look at it with ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Image`RecognitionDump`standardizeFormatNames]``.